# If `so` stands for shared object, then what does `a` stand for?

Tags: linux, unix, posix

Majority of *nix operating systems use `.so` as extension name for shared objects (libraries) and `.a` as extension name for static objects.

If `so` stands for shared object, then what does `a` stand for?

Comment: `ar`chive would be the best definition.

Comment: @devnull I do believe that the question is a practical, answerable question that is unique to software development, therefore it is on-topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A static library also known as an `archive`. So it is `.a` extension.

[Static and dynamic libraries](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a1-static-and-dynamic-libraries/)

Comment: +1: based on the `ar` (archive) command used to manipulate the contents of a `.a` library. And the reason for the `libxxx.a` convention is that if you specify `-lxxx` on the command line, the linker will look for `libxxx.so` and `libxxx.a` to satisfy its needs.  You can use other extensions (e.g. `xxx.lib`) but then you have to specify the path to the library on the command line. That's fighting against the system, which is unnecessarily hard work, so most people don't do it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler post your above command as answer. I like to give upvote.